# PHP mpdf error in PHP 8.0 (imagecreatefromstring())

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mpdf

mpdf package worked well for generating PDF on below PHP 7.4 without any issue. I upgraded the PHP version on my local and when I run the project, I am getting this error. I didn't use PNG file for generating PDF. I upgraded the images from PNGs to JPG after I got this error, but I am getting the same error.

This is error message. Could you help me if you faced this kind of issue. Thanks.

> Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): gd-png: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile in C:\xampp\htdocs\fasttestnow\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\src\Image\ImageProcessor.php on line 552